# partially editable string in a textbox control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

is there a way to allow editing a string partially in c# and wpf textbox?
somthing , if the contents of the TextBox were for example

```
"http://xxxx.xxx/xx/path?param1=xxx&param2=xxx"
```

the x can be replaced with whatever length but any thing else is constant and cannot be edited in the textbox, any way to achive such thing?

Comment: Have you tried a masked textbox?

Comment: @BSoD_ZA i will check it out

Comment: Masked textbox may be hard with a complex pattern like that. Maybe a few textboxes next to each other so it reads like one text?

Comment: The suggestion made by @Szymon was perfectly reasonable and there is nothing in your question to hint that that was not acceptable. Please remember that we are trying to help you, so a little bit of politeness couldn't hurt.

Comment: @Sheridan didn't mean to and he knows it, i was just saying that ofcurse the first thing that would come to mind is using seperate boxes

Comment: I'm just about to get off my high horse now, but before I do, I'd just like to point out that what is obvious to you might not be obvious to everyone else. Remember that this site is used worldwide and there is also often a language barrier. Now hopefully you understand my reason for commenting and haven't taken any offence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two relevant events that you can handle on the `TextBox`; the [`PreviewKeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown.aspx) and the [`PreviewTextInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput.aspx) events. By handling these two events, you will have complete control over what the user can and can't edit in the `TextBox`. Of course you will need to work out the logic inside, but the event handlers are the tool to enable you to do what you want:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Do your text filtering here using e.Key and e.Handled
}

private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    // Do your text filtering here using e.Text and e.Handled
}
```